# Dpi/Screen Resol. Test-Case [Ubuntu-Desktop] (seemed to be better with Nouveau) -- Xorg Display Server vs. Proprietary Nvidia .Xorg Drivers

Tags: video, hybrid-graphics, display-resolution, dpi, nvidia-settings

When I first installed Ubuntu I noticed that the plymouth display screen (command-line initialization display or w.e.) Was printing lines of high-dpi text, and just as well, the desktop environment looked really good...

Qualitatively, the screen resolution seemed to be perfect. I also noticed (for the first time) the name of the nouveau display driver while plymouth was busy 'tickering' away, outputting status messages for the loading of initial modules.

## Now, the peculiarity of the bootstraping screen ... ,

Now, the peculiarity of the bootstraping screen, which had intrigued me, was the comparison between the display output in that situation and the Dpi/Font/Desktop screen resolution; either with nvidias proprietary `'X'` drivers, or going without native Nvidia compatible drivers installed.

I should note that, in different circumstances, I've been able (lol) to screw things up with the OS , time-and-agaiin, rather incessantly within the span of a month or so (in various ways)... I had only taken interest of the difference between the qualities of display output when, after executing `sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade` that automatically broke the compatibility of most graphics software Packages. Init was unable to `startx`, blablabla...

I rather needed to use the recovery-mode "tty" terminals to try and resolve some issues; at once, it occured to me that the resolution and aspect of the whole screen looked better than usual-- after the OS booted properly, with the standard "from-scratch" video card detection Firmware, and including the `'Xorg-nouveau'*` Display Module.

I wonder how the heck the driver for Nvidia, supposedly being native to the computer's graphics card/architecture, would end up scaling down the resolution by just a tiny fraction. How irksome, it is...

I know this isn't a graphics optimization setting --, as evidenced by the fact the Xorg `'nvidia-settings'` Panel readout mentions capabilities of relaying rendered graphics to a maximum of two screens in tandem (btw I'm using a netbook), as well as being able to render frames for outputting at a resolution somewhat greater then the aspect ratio of my LCD screen.

## ^

Towit, that statement might be a bit of an oxymoron; it calls to mind the fact that Netbooks have well-integrated power management programs with universal policy control [sic]; PCI Bus "link-State" management; variable processor timing/threading,etc.

So,the lower-res(dpi) rendering of the desktop environment may only be the default configuration, for the purpose of balancing the card's hi-graphics capabilities with the rest of its efficiency and video-rendering acceleration. Although, I'm uncertain that I can see how the Xorg-server API manages these properties, despite looking for more specification beside the guise of the Nvidia settings PowerMiser UI.

But, in saying this I digress; I am yet too novice to be able to sift through mounds of configuration options etc, myself, in this area of inquiry.

### Notwithstanding, Ubuntu+nouveau seemed like they worked well- enough, to boot ...,

Notwithstanding that, Ubuntu+nouveau seemed like they worked well enough, I should mention. seeming to have have a higher default video resolution than the Nv. driver at first run (as compared with my clean installs which were configured with the proprietary drivers).

This smacks of something screw-y, and it could involve an unfair comparison of two really decent Display APIs, to really critique in this manner of speaking, despite their obvious differences (i.e. pros/cons of native graphics firmware vs. special processing capabilities; like, CUDA, par example.

The difference was amazing, the fact that the nouveau driver, integrates so well with the detected hardware , I want to know how easy it would be, figuratively, to set that same high Dpi/Resolution, using the proprietary Nvidia Driver.

#### Right now I'm using the Ubuntu Live installation, just so...,

And its current (Trusty 14.10) configuration, is now complete with the Nouveau Xorg Driver. The difference is night and day; without regard for a few caveat.

I just like the customization aspects of the options in the Nvidia panel, and the slick graphics-acceleration API (GLX -- going great with VideoLan VLC media player). I wish I knew the nature of the peculiar discrepancies about the Xorg drivers , and the video-resolution of the  LCD).